# Probability for 3 points $a$, $b$, $c$ chosen from $N$ points given their sum is constant, such that $a+b\ge c$, i.e, it can form a triangle.

Tags: probability, number-theory, real-numbers, recursion

**Question:**

$$x_1 + x_2 + ... +x_N = \text{constant}$$
Given only that $N$ and $\text{constant}$ are real numbers, $x>0$, $N\ge 2$.

> Find probability of choosing 3 numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ from $N$ numbers such that 
>   $$a+b\ge c$$ 
>   (i.e. it must  form a triangle).

**My solution:** 
I am trying to solve it using recursion as i have no mathematical knowledge about it,but i could not solve,
**How to solve it mathematically.**

Comment: What does it mean for the maximal index $N$ to be a real number?

Comment: In the title, you added a condition that's not in the text. $a+b\ge c$ doesn't guarantee that $a$, $b$ and $c$ could form a triangle -- you could still have $b+c\lt a$. (Anyway it should be $a+b\gt c$, not $\ge$, if it's supposed to be part of triangle condition.)

Comment: Assuming that you intended $N$ to be an integer and that you do only have the condition $a+b\ge c$, the question is still no well-defined, as the answer depends on the $x_i$. For instance, if they're all the same, the probability is $1$, which is clearly not true in other cases. My guess would be that perhaps you intended for the $x_i$ to be random, too, and to be uniformly chosen from the simplex defined by $\sum_ix_i=c$?

Comment: what do u mean by simplex

Comment: as they are real number they can differ by small amount but still form a triangle hence a+b>=c is same as a+b>c

Comment: Never mind about the [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex); I just meant the set defined by $\sum_ix_i=c$. And no, it's not the same, they either differ or they don't, and if you allow equality then you can't form a triangle (unless you want to allow degenerate triangles, in which case I think you should mention that because that's not what "triangle" is conventionally understood to mean).